# Running a Linux Command through a Java GUI

Tags: java, linux, terminal, command, runtime.exec

I can get my terminal to show up but I can't get my code to run: and always get the exception. Any idea what's wrong?

```
if (e.getActionCommand() == "Start") {
String command= "/usr/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/pgsql/data -l /var/lib/pgsql/log/pgsql.log     start"; 
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
try {
rt.exec(command);
} catch (IOException e1) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please post the exception and stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

It is mentioned in `Runtime docs` that if you want to execute `command and arguments` you need to pass it as a String array  `exec(String[] cmdarray)`

[Runtime doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)